# Django Pydocs / reading the Django Documentation

Tags: python, django, pydoc, django-contrib

Since the Django online documentation only provides code examples, and doesn't really provide a simple module / class reference, I'm trying to read the pydocs locally but keep running into this problem.

#### pydoc django error message:

[image: pydoc django error message]

I'm running the pydoc3 -p local server to browse the documentation. Why is it generating this error, and how can I fix it?